# How to access a variable from the parent class

Tags: c++, class, variables, parent

How can I access a variable from a parent class? I thought the below code would do this, but when I try to print out the value of name in Controller.cpp I get the error:

> Member access into incomplete type 'TestApp'

**TestApp.cpp**

```
#include "cinder/app/AppNative.h"
#include "Controller.h"

using namespace ci;
using namespace ci::app;
using namespace std;

class TestApp : public AppNative
{
  public:
    void setup();
    void update();

    string name = "Parent";

    Controller controller;
};

void TestApp::setup()
{
    controller.setup(this);
}

void TestApp::update()
{
    controller.update();
}


CINDER_APP_NATIVE( TestApp, RendererGl )
```

**Controller.h**

```
#pragma once

class TestApp;

class Controller
{
    public:
        void setup(TestApp* parent);
        void update();
        TestApp* p;
};
```

**Controller.cpp**

```
#include "Controller.h"

void Controller::setup(TestApp* parent)
{
    p = parent;
}

void Controller::update()
{
    std::cout << p->name << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing to do with parent classes. `TestApp` is defined in TestApp.cpp, it's not visible to the code in Controller.cpp. You need to move the definition of `TestApp` to a header file (called TestApp.h say) and then `#include "TestApp.h"` in Controller.cpp.

Comment: In my testing I had been adding `#include "TestApp.h` in Controller.h instead of in Controller.cpp, I didn't realise that made a difference!

Answer (score 2):

You need to put the `TestApp` class definition in a header, and include that in `TestApp.cpp` and `Controller.cpp`.

Answer (score 0):

Class Controller knows nothing about what dara members class TestApp has. It knows only that there is class TestApp that is defined somewhere else.